# probability of two ore more misprints in a 500 page book

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

I'm trying to improve my probability theory and came across the following question which I am struggling with. Suppose there is a 500 page book with 500 misprints in it. What is the probability that a given page will have two or more misprints?

I want to give an approximation of this using that the binomial distribution is approximated by the Poisson distribution. In this case $n = 500$ and the probability of a misprint on any page is $p = 1/500$. So the probability of there being exactly $k$ misprints on a given page is approximately

$$
 \frac{1}{k!}e^{-1}
$$

thus the probability of two or more misprints on the same page is approximately given by

$$
1 - e^{-1} - e^{-1} = 1-2e^{-1}.
$$

However, the book I am using claims the answer is $1- \frac{5}{2}e^{-1}$. I am not sure where this fraction is coming from. Is this claimed answer itself a misprint?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: To me your solution looks correct. The probability that a misprint falls on a certain page is $p=1/500\,.$ Therefore, the probability that a given page has no misprint is $(1-p)^{500}\,,$ resp. has one misprint is $500\cdot p(1-p)^{499}\,.$ (Binomial distribution.) Subtracting these two values from one gives $0.26424$ which is very close to your approximation.

Comment: It's rather funny if there's a misprint in that context. What book is this in and at what location in the book?

Comment: @KurtG. thanks good to know! I felt that my reasoning was correct, so I found the answer in the book a bit strange and wanted to verify I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @Lorents Its from "Probability Theory: A Concise Course" by Rozanov, the specific question is from Chapter 5 problem 4.

Comment: If the given question is "What is the probability that a given page will have 3 or more misprints?" , then the answer given by the book is correct.

Comment: @user295357 or equivalently "What is the probability that a given page will have more than two misprints?" to get closer to the quoted wording

Comment: That's true, but the working specifically says two or more misprints.

Comment: The book was originally written in Russian. It may have been some phrasing meaning "more than two" in the original, but was mistranslated to "two or more" in English.